# Is it possible to use Postgres extensions like postgis directly in edgdedb?

Tags: postgis, edgedb

I'm new to EdgeDB and want to use it in my current project. The issue is I'm using the `postgis` extension extensively right now. I am aware that supporting `gis` is on EdgeDB's roadmap, but is there a way to use it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to use postgres extensions generally or postgis specifically. As noted, gis support is planned as well as a generic extension system.